# PHP $_GET method is not working on server but working on local host

Tags: php, .htaccess, bootstrap-4

I am facing a issue with GET method,
I have 2 pages with name index.php and packages.php...
index.php generated POST method request and passing values to the package.php using the below code

```
if(isset($_POST["categorystring"])){
$retval = $_POST["categorystring"];
header("location:packages/category/".php_slug($retval)."");
}elseif(isset($_POST["allpackage"])){
$retval = $_POST["allpackage"];
//var_dump($retval);
header("location:packages/details/all-packages/1");
}

function php_slug($string)  
{  
    list($categoryid, $categoryname) = explode(":",$string);
  $url = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $categoryname))."/".$categoryid;
  $slug = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9-]+/', '-', trim(strtolower($url)));  
  return $url;  
}
```

and another side on packages.php I am using GET to retrive the values as:

```
if(isset($_GET['categorystring'])) {
  $getstring=$_GET['categorystring'];
  list($stringname, $id) = explode("/",$getstring);
$stringname = str_replace("-"," ",$stringname);
$querystring = "category";

}elseif(isset($_GET['allpackage'])) {
  $getstring =$_GET['allpackage'];
  list($stringname, $id) = explode("/",$getstring);
 $stringname = str_replace("-"," ",$stringname);
$querystring = "allpackages";
}
```

MY URL IS AS FOR package.php

http://localhost/ladakh/packages/category/mountaineering-in-ladakh/2

as I am also using .htaccess for making user friendly URL with PHP as

```
RewriteRule ^packages/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ packages.php? 
categorystring=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^packages/details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ packages.php?allpackage=$1 
[NC,L]
```

It works fine in local host but not working on server as I changed the PHP version from 5.4 to 7.1 on server but the output is same...

What may be the cause of this ????

Comment: And "does not work" means what exactly?

Comment: there is a problem with your .htaccess file not with PHP 
you can check webserver which you are using in Server if you are using Nginx .htaccess file will not work
if you are using Apache then check `mod_rewrite` is on and check error log and access log of apache server so you can get more idea about this

Comment: And please start using standard indentation. Your code is much easier to read then, in its current form you only make it difficult for everyone else to understand your code. _Why?_

Comment: @arkascha, when i add else in package.php, it display the contents of else condition only

Comment: @shailesh dudhat, if .htaccess is not working then how its matching the rule that is mentioned in that file

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to say in your question, sorry. Please try to be more precise. Where should those POST values come from? You state that your `index.php` script "generated" a POST request.... How that? Where is the code doing that?

Comment: How do you know that your rewriting rules actually do get applied? Have you dumped the contents of `$_GET` into a log file to check? What does it contain?

Comment: @arkascha sir, yes, index.php is generating POST and all are working fine on local machine.

Comment: Sorry, but just repeating what you already wrote does not help. I asked a question, you did not answer to that question.

Comment: No sir, i have not dumped the contents of $_GET as i am not aware about this.

Comment: Well, if `$_GET` does obviously not contain what you expect, then wouldn't it make sense to check what it actually contains? Go and do that!

Comment: @Nandani, you can print all $_GET variables by `print_r($_GET)` try on package.php and as well as you can try with `print_r($_REQUEST)` as well so you can get to know what is coming inside

Comment: OKAY, lets discuss on this POST and GET only first.
I have some different categories and id in index.php and on the basis of that i want to change the url.
and in package.php i also want to read the categories with id to perform the functionality

Comment: i have alread checked this with var_dump($_GET['passed string']
and i got mountaineering-in-ladakh/2 for passed string="categorystring"
on local host but i m not getting anything in server as i already told on this, i also checked it with  adding else condition with categorystring and allpackages 
then else part work on server

Comment: Server display NULL NULL for 
var_dump($_GET['categorystring']);
var_dump($_GET['allpackage']);

Comment: @shaileshdudhat sir, yes mod_rewrite is on

Comment: So, no one has solution of my problem... awww :(

Comment: @Nandani, try for printing all `print_r($_GET)` and `print_r($_REQUEST)`
so u will get all the variable which you are getting in get or post method in that check for your categorystring and allpackage

Comment: sir, on server i can see NULL for GET and REQUEST.. The problem may be in .htaccess or php.ini but I am not sure on this

Comment: Empty array with $_GET Print 
Array
(
)
Array
(
    [vsid] =&gt; 917vr2925735166820624
    [bfp_sn_rf_b10ce94cf299b167b74a6944e0aec9d4] =&gt; Direct/External
    [bfp_sn_rt_b10ce94cf299b167b74a6944e0aec9d4] =&gt; 1545029438352
    [bafp] =&gt; 100fd1f0-01c8-11e9-9ef5-cb63c1e7553d
    [PHPSESSID] =&gt; mfrm9th61261rtbjpcqlaj04h5
    [cpsession] =&gt; hotelszg:LqAoaSimF6RhJQZN,bfbec7d754f9d7c7210835c2e6021806
)

Comment: @Nandani, tried your htaccess code in local, it was not working in my local system as well then in first line when i added this line it's working for me.
`RewriteEngine on`
in .htaccess file add this in first line. and make sure both RewriteRule you are writing in one line only

Comment: sir, i only shared the partial code.. here is the full code
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
RewriteEngine On  
##RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images)/(.*)$ $1

RewriteRule ^packages/category/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ packages.php?categorystring=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^packages/details/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)?$ packages.php?allpackage=$1 [NC,L]

Comment: hi, same code is working with another hosting provider server like godaddy but not working on hostgator....
   Something is wrong with php.ini as i have selected php version 7.0 on both server.